# Efficiently creating a LayoutInflater

Tags: android, android-context, android-inflate

My question is what is the best way to create a `LayoutInflater` instance? Is there any difference between

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

and

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Which is the better solution? Other solutions are also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you checked the LayoutInflater.java source file you would find.

```
/**
 * Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.
 */
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}
```

Comment: So the second solution should be a little efficient than the First One.